# Trigonometric equation....

Tags: trigonometry

Can you please check my solved exercise. I'm not totally sure about it. Thank you in advance![image]

Note!!! In the condition it should be  "8cosx".
sinx can't be less than -1

Comment: $2\sin2x - 4 + \not8\cos x -2\sin x = 0$

Comment: Where does $8\cos(x)$ come from?

Comment: Excuse me  the exercise contains 8cosx I just made a mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first value is is given by $\cos x=\frac12$, and $\pi/3 + 2\pi n$ is not included in your domain.

> But the first value of $x$ is also wrong because it's not contained in the domain of the 
>   function.

**Hint**: sketch the curve for $\cos x$ and see if there are other values of $x$ that satisfy $\cos x=\frac12$ in the domain. The symmetry of the cosine curve should show you where the solution is or you can use an appropriate trig identity.

[image]